# C# WinForms Tray application - not catching windows shutdown events

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, shutdown

I'm writing a program that monitors state. It launches main window (LoginForm) to ask for user credentials, then hides the form. After that LoginForm inits NotifyIcon and all the remaining work is being done with LoginForm hidden. I've implemented all the clean-up work in FormClosing event of LoginForm. During normal exit process everything works perfectly.

The problem is that the program sits in tray all the time and I tend to forget to exit it before shutting down windows - program doesn't save the state on shutdown event.

I've read through many forums and docs, and from what I've read events FormClosing/FormClosed + SessionEnding/SessionEnded must fire anyway. But it looks like they just don't fire. Can't even cancel shutdown in SessionEnding (with stupid e.Cancel=true) - program disappears without reaching the place.

I've made myself a small debugging library to write out debug information into a file with instant flashing of cache. I've added debug messages to all the events. When I try to log off user in Windows (same as shutting down) for a test - I see no events being triggered usually, just the program vanishes. No exceptions I could catch, no events, etc. When exitting program manually or through "taskkill /IM " - I see all the expected debug printout. What's even more interesting - sometimes the program does reach closing events and does proper clean-up job during Windows shutdown.

Wasted a few days on this already. Overriden WndProc as suggested in MS article - program doesn't reach WndProc as well (to ensure it comes first before closing the form). Tried instead of FormClosing event to override OnClosing of LoginForm - no luck. Added UnhandledException handler, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEnding, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEnded, Form.FormClosing, Form.FormClosed event handlers - no luck.

I suspect this is either a problem of hidden forms or that some kind of exception is happening during shutdown only (resources disposed?). How can I find why that's happening? Is there some simple way to simulate Windows shutdown for single application to make debugging in VS possible? I've tried RMTool - for some reason it fails to simulate shutdown and program just ignores it.

**Update:** Program uses System.Timers.Timer to regularly poll server for any changes.

Comment: Have you tried adding your clean-up code in your Program class, after the Application.Run line?  Unless Windows force kills your application, code in the Program Main method will always run.  This is where I often put a try..catch around to catch and log all unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @Russ Nope, will try it, thanks for idea.

Comment: @Russ Unfortunately app didn't reach code after Application.Run in Main method.

Comment: Quick hack--save your state every X minutes.  Or, save an intermittent state at a known location, check on startup, and recover.

Comment: It sounds like Windows is killing the process outright.  Normally, when Windows shuts down, it signals applications to soft-close, so that any and all clean-up can occur.  If the application takes too long to do this, the user gets the message that the application is holding up shutdown and asks if you want to close anyhow--which would then forcably kill the  processes that are holding up shutdown.  At this point, I'm not sure why Windows would do that to your app.  Are you running any unmanaged code (P/Invoke stuff) that could be confusing Windows somehow?

Comment: What @Will said. If you can't catch terminate event reliably, then ensure what you loose as less as possible (from last auto-save).

Comment: @Sinatr It also saves your butt when your app crashes :)

Comment: @Will saving state as XML and it takes up ~1 MB. Data is quite easy to obtain again, so I don't want to thrash HDD excessively. Saving state on app shutdown lets user to avoid a bit of additional work checking manually initial state (program tracks changes between old and new state, saving state gives old state info). I've considered auto-saving, but it's not an option here.

Comment: @Russ Windows shouldn't just kill application. Also, behavior is not consistent. Sometimes app still catches proper events and I get the right footprint in debug log. Though I was not able to make out the pattern yet.

Comment: @chersun oooooo 1mb!  Bro, that's crazy data there.  Maybe you should gzip the stream?  Autosave of state doesn't thrash the disk. Calm thy chests.  Office and other applications do this all the time, it isn't bad.  Look, you're not getting what you expect because it isn't reliable. That sucks, but that's life. You have to be defensive about this.  I don't have any other advice, so good luck, and good day to you!

Comment: @chersun--right, that is what I'm saying--Windows SHOULDN'T just kill it, at least not without asking the user first, but it is behaving as if it is. My asking about unmanaged code is because a thought is that some unmanaged routine is getting lost in RAM somewhere, causing strange things to happen--it's stuff I've seen before.  Though, I'll admit at this point I'm shooting in the dark.  Finding that pattern will definitely get you closer.

Comment: @Russ Minor unmanaged code to flash taskbar icon, to bring window to the top without stealing focus, etc. SLC posted nice article which could be a workaround - to temporarily block shutdown until app can finish it's work.

Comment: @Will I'm trying to make app to have as small footprint as possible. That includes disk and memory and user visual space. I see your point on auto-saving, though I cannot accept it in this case. I tried to explain why as best as I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some research into this, basically, after Windows XP they altered the way that shutdowns were handled.

You cannot block or capture the shutdown event reliably using the form_closing events etc.

You must use a new API to do so. There is a complete example here: [http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/25/Windows-Vista-*2D00*-ShutdownBlockReasonCreate-in-C_2300_.aspx](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/25/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-ShutdownBlockReasonCreate-in-C_2300_.aspx)

You should be able to call the function to block shutting down (display a message such as 'saving changes...') and then save and exit your application in the background. Once your program quits, it should allow windows to continue shutting down.

Comment: Looks very promising. I'll come back once I test this.

Comment: Tested with clean project. Clean project gets no events if it runs from inside Visual Studio. But outside of VS it gets all notifications as expected. Looks like some resource mismanagement in my case. Then this solution is exactly what I need to prevent shutdown until I finish the job. Thank you, SLC.

Comment: With shutdown blocking enabled I was able to find, that another form was getting FormClosing event with Reason = WindowsShutdown instead of main form.

Comment: No problem. Good to hear that you can capture some event, I was worried there would be no closing events for you to hook into! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think windows is simply configured to automatically shutdown all applications regardless and hence the application has no chance to catch SessionEnding events and so on : have a look at http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/disable-automatic-termination-of-applications-during-shutdown-in-windows-7/ or check your configuration at Computer Configurations > Administrative Templates > System > Shutdown Options.

Comment: By default doesn't it block - having Notepad open with changes in has been preventing shutdowns since time began

Comment: @Ahmad I've checked this as well and disabled some time ago, just to make sure. Behavior didn't change.

Comment: @SLC Yes, I'm keeping notepad open just to avoid entering my password over and over again. It doesn't make any change to my app, that is run later then notepad. The app still disappears. All the other software keeps running with notepad blocking actual logoff.